# What is the most efficient medium for both Node.js and Javascript to read and write a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can JavaScript *simply* receive incoming data from Node.js which received that data from an external server? I have searched for days trying to figure out a way to do this. Here is one that I have thought of:

Every few seconds, I will have both server-side Node.js and client-side JavaScript setInterval() an HTML list (which I would guess is the medium between Javascript and Node) every 1000 milliseconds. If there is data in this variable, the JavaScript part will take it, use it accordingly, and set that variable to

```
input = ""
```

and when the node socket receives data from a distant Java server, it will add that data to the next element in that list if JavaScript hasn't taken and cleared it yet.

```
var client = new net.Socket();
  client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      //I have not gotten as far as adding it to a list yet, so for now let  
      //a variable named "input" be sufficient.
      res.render('index', { input: data.toString(), condition: false });
    });
  });
```

JavaScript shall read this list for elements or in this case variable (if possible; I've looked on Google to no avail: entries on Google included "JavaScript reading and setting HTML variable" among many others) and clear it when it is finished.

Is this the optimal way to do this? In any case, how should JavaScript receive this data from Node which receives it by Java?

Comment: You might find your questions get a better response if you hold off being a jerk until at least a few sentences in. What is the file you mention in the title? If you just mean how to transfer data from the server to the front end, then some kind of JSON API , either http calls or over a web socket, would be the convention, not involving files (and certainly not using HTML as the transfer medium, for which it's not at all suited). How the front end renders that new data for the user is then a separate issue.

Comment: Please describe your actual use case - the actual problem you are trying to solve.  You've tried to outline a solution without really describing the problem and, as such, we can't really understand what you're trying to do and offer the best type of answer.  Start with describing where the data is coming from and how one knows there is new data.  Then, describe where you want the data to end up when everything is done.  We can then make suggestions for what to do in the middle to facilitate that.  Getting good answers here requires understand how to write a good, clear question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but I think you can achieve what you want with Socket.io and a simple file writer.